# AngularJS: Pass a scope function to a directive inside a JSN object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a directive that, based on a trigger value, displays one of a number of combinations of label and action link in a div.

The label and trigger value are specified in their own attributes - no issues so far.

The actions, seeing as there can be any number, are defined in an `actions` attribute. This is a JSON encoded array of objects, each one representing one possible action link.

Everything is working fine when I use it like so:

```
<record-milestone
        label="'Login Details'" test-value="member.login_details_sent"
        action="sendLoginDetails(member)"
        actions="[
                {'test': 'testResult !== null', 'label': member.login_details_sent.toDateString(), 'actionable': false, 'className': 'progressmsgyes'},
                {'test': 'testResult === null', 'label': 'Send...', 'actionable': true, 'className': 'progressmsgno', 'default': true}
                ]">
</record-milestone>
```

Note especially the `member.login_details_sent.toDateString()` bit.

I want instead to use a function defined as part of `$scope` to produce the label - like so...

```
<record-milestone
        label="'Membership Fee'" test-value="member.membership_fee_paid"
        action="setDate(member, 'membership_fee_paid')"
        actions="[
                {'test': 'testResult !== null', 'label': getDateString(member.membership_fee_paid), 'actionable': false, 'className': 'progressmsgyes', 'default': true},
                {'test': 'testResult === null', 'label': 'Paid...', 'actionable': true, 'className': 'progressmsgno'}
                ]">
</record-milestone>
```

In this case, the action label, which should take the value of `getDateString(member.membership_fee_paid)` is blank. Adding an alert to the function itself reveals it is not being called at all. My best guess is that the directive isn't treating it as a function.

Is there a way to pass a scope function to the directive through an array like this or am I completely off track?

I'm still learning AngularJS, and this is my first effort at a non-trivial directive so I'm not above a rewrite if I've gone the wrong way about it.

Here's the rest of the code.

**recordmilestone.js**

```
/**
 * Displays a bar showing a label and value, allowing an action. Action can vary depending on the value.
 *
 * Attributes:
 *  - label - The label for the bar
 *  - testValue - An expression to be evaluated an d compared against the 'test' element of the actions array
 *  - action - An expression to be executed when the action button is clicked
 *  - actions - Array of Objects. For each object:
 *      - 'test' is an expression that is evaluated to determine whether this action is used. This is executed in the
 *         directive's isolated scope so does not have access to the controller's scope variables. testResult can be used
 *         to represent the expression in the testValue attribute.
 *      - 'label' is the label to be displayed for the action button if the test resolves to true,
 *      - 'actionable' determines whether the action link should be clickable - if true a link is shown, if false it is
 *        shown simply as text
 *      - 'className' is the class to apply to the element
 *      - 'default' (optional) if true, this action is applied if no other rules match. If more than one action is
 *        specified as default, the last action with `default: true` is used.
 *
 * Example usage:
 * <record-milestone
 *      label="Stage 1" test-value="stage1.complete" action="item.complete = true"
 *      actions="[
 *          {'test': true, 'label': 'Completed', 'actionable': false, 'className': 'progressmsgyes'},
 *          {'test': false, 'label': 'Mark complete', 'actionable': true, 'className': 'progressmsgno', 'default': true}
 *      ]">
 *
 */

directives.directive('recordMilestone',
[
function() {
    //Define the controller
    var controller = ['$scope', '$parse', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $parse, $rootScope) {

        //Watch the value
        $scope.$watch(function() {
                return $parse($scope.testValue)();
            },
            function(newValue) {
                $scope.testResult = newValue;

                //Evaluate actions array
                //Array.some() executes the callback for each element until one returns true. Better than forEach() which
                //can't be interrupted
                $scope.actions.some( function(action) {
                    if( $parse(action.test)($scope) || action.default ) {

                        $scope.actionLabel = action.label;
                        $scope.actionLabelBackup = action.label;
                        $scope.className = action.className;
                        $scope.actionable = action.actionable;
                        $scope.uploadAction = action.uploadAction | false;

                        //Return true if the value matched, false otherwise
                        return $parse(action.test)($scope);
                    }

                    return false;

                });

            });

        $scope.doAction = function() {
            $scope.action();
        }

        $scope.uploadStarted = function(files) {
            $scope.actionLabel = 'Uploading...';
        }

        $scope.uploadFailed = function (response) {
            $scope.actionLabel = $scope.actionLabelBackup;

            alert("Upload failed: " + response.data.errormessage);
        }

    }];


    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        templateUrl: '/app/shared/directives/recordMilestoneTemplate.html',

        controller: controller,

        scope: {
            label: '=',
            testValue: '&',
            actions: '=',
            action: '&',
            uploadUrl: '=',
            uploadComplete: '&'
        }
    }
}]);
```

**recordMilestoneTemplate.html**

```
<div ng-class="className">
    <a ng-if="actionable && !uploadAction" ng-click="doAction()">{{actionLabel}}</a>
    <div class="btn-upload"
         ng-if="actionable && uploadAction"
         upload-button
         url="{{uploadUrl}}"
         on-upload="uploadStarted(files)"
         on-error="uploadFailed(response)"
         on-success="uploadComplete(response)"
         >{{actionLabel}}</div>
    <div ng-if="!actionable">{{actionLabel}}</div>
    {{label}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem.

The issue wasn't that it didn't know how to run the function defined in the array, it was that no digest loop was started when the result of the function changed.

The element defined in the directive is created when the details for a record are shown (after a click by the user). This is followed by a HTTP GET to fetch the information itself.

When the directive is first created, the `member.membership_fee_paid` value is blank. The directive is created (with a blank label, because of the missing value) and then the data is populated.

As simple `$scope.$watch` on the `actions` attribute forcing the internal label variables to be updated solved the problem.